# can't get panel added to jtabbed pane after calling setComponentAt()

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have added a custom panel named MyEditorPanel which extends JPanel to JTabbedPanel and want a close button on each tab in order to do that i have used following code and used ButtonTabbedComponent.java from [ButtonTabbedComponent.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TabComponentsDemoProject/src/components/ButtonTabComponent.java)

```
public void addTab(String name, String desc) {
    MyEditorPane textEditorPane = new MyEditorPane(this, name, desc);
    this.addTab(name, normal, textEditorPane, desc);
    int i = this.getComponentCount() - 1;
    textEditorPane.setTabCount(i);
    this.setTabComponentAt(i, new ButtonTabComponent(this, normal, normalFont));
}
```

but i want to save text in MyEditorPane before closing how can i get which MyEditorPane is being going to close on close button clicked

when i get the name of components in JTabbedPane class it does not have MyEditorPane class object

```
@Override
public void remove(int index) {

Component component = this.getTabComponentAt(index);
if (component instanceof ButtonTabComponent) {
    ButtonTabComponent tab = (ButtonTabComponent) component;
    System.out.println("remove method called if : " + tab.getComponentCount());
    component = tab.getComponent(0);
    System.out.println("remove method called if : " + component.getClass().getName());

    component = tab.getComponent(1);
    System.out.println("remove method called if : " + component.getClass().getName());
    JPanel pane = (JPanel) component;
    Component[] components = pane.getComponents();
    for (int i = 0, l = components.length; i < l; i++) {
            System.out.println("remove method called for : " + components[i].getClass().getName());                
    }
    super.remove(index);
}
}
```

output of method remove

```
remove method called if : 2
remove method called if : javax.swing.JLabel
remove method called if : javax.swing.JPanel
remove method called for : pkginterface.ButtonTabComponent$1
remove method called for : pkginterface.ButtonTabComponent$TabButton
```

Comment: `ButtonTabComponent` won't contain your instance of `MyEditorPane`, it would be contained by the `JTabbedPane`

Comment: What will be index of tab that contain MyEditorPane

Comment: You should have a look at [How to Use Tabbed Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), which demonstrates the basic concept, but which also seems to be what your code is based on. Something like `int i = pane.indexOfTabComponent(ButtonTabComponent.this);`, which then allows you to use `pane.remove(i)`

Comment: i have read that and i am using it but i want not to remove the tab before save

Comment: how i know that MyEditorPane has changed or not

Comment: That's something you will have to devise, once you have a reference to the tab's component, you can cast it and ask it.  If it's changed, you can further query the user and if they cancel, you can avoid closing the tab

Comment: that is what i am trying to do when i checked the class name of that tab component it is ButtonTabComponent not MyEditorPane

Comment: So, calling `int i = pane.indexOfTabComponent(ButtonTabComponent.this);` will give you the index of the component...

Comment: i uses that int i = pane.indexOfTabComponent(ButtonTabComponent.this);
            if (i != -1) {
                pane.remove(i);
            }

Comment: and overide remove method in Output class which extends TabbedPane

Comment: which is listed above and when used if(component instanceof MyEditorPane) gives error of casting

Comment: That because you're getting the components from the actual "tab", not the tab pane

Comment: how to get component from tab pane?

Comment: Take a look at the answer, which has a runnable example. One of the things I do is get the "component" for the tab's view (which in the case of the example is a `JLabel`) and print it's text

Comment: Solved i am calling getTabComponentAt() instead of getComponentAt() thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 2):

So, based on the example from [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), you could use something like...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int i = pane.indexOfTabComponent(ButtonTabComponent.this);
    if (i != -1) {
        Component comp = pane.getComponentAt(i);
        if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) comp;
            System.out.println("Label text = " + label.getText());
            switch (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure you want to close the \"" + pane.getTitleAt(i) + "\" tab?", "Close", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION)) {
                case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
                    pane.remove(i);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to determine the tab which is been closed, find the component which is acting as the tabs view, ask the user if they want to close this particular tab or not and take appropriate action based on their feedback

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI;

public class TabComponentsDemo extends JFrame {

    private final int tabNumber = 5;
    private final JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
    private JMenuItem tabComponentsItem;
    private JMenuItem scrollLayoutItem;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                new TabComponentsDemo("TabComponentsDemo").runTest();
            }
        });
    }

    public TabComponentsDemo(String title) {
        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initMenu();
        add(pane);
    }

    public void runTest() {
        pane.removeAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabNumber; i++) {
            String title = "Tab " + i;
            pane.add(title, new JLabel(title));
            initTabComponent(i);
        }
        tabComponentsItem.setSelected(true);
        pane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT);
        scrollLayoutItem.setSelected(false);
        setSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initTabComponent(int i) {
        pane.setTabComponentAt(i,
                new ButtonTabComponent(pane));
    }

    //Setting menu
    private void initMenu() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        //create Options menu
        tabComponentsItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Use TabComponents", true);
        tabComponentsItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_T, InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        tabComponentsItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < pane.getTabCount(); i++) {
                    if (tabComponentsItem.isSelected()) {
                        initTabComponent(i);
                    } else {
                        pane.setTabComponentAt(i, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        scrollLayoutItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Set ScrollLayout");
        scrollLayoutItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        scrollLayoutItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (pane.getTabLayoutPolicy() == JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT) {
                    pane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
                } else {
                    pane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT);
                }
            }
        });
        JMenuItem resetItem = new JMenuItem("Reset JTabbedPane");
        resetItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R, InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        resetItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                runTest();
            }
        });

        JMenu optionsMenu = new JMenu("Options");
        optionsMenu.add(tabComponentsItem);
        optionsMenu.add(scrollLayoutItem);
        optionsMenu.add(resetItem);
        menuBar.add(optionsMenu);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

    public static class ButtonTabComponent extends JPanel {

        private final JTabbedPane pane;

        public ButtonTabComponent(final JTabbedPane pane) {
            //unset default FlowLayout' gaps
            super(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));
            if (pane == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("TabbedPane is null");
            }
            this.pane = pane;
            setOpaque(false);

            //make JLabel read titles from JTabbedPane
            JLabel label = new JLabel() {
                public String getText() {
                    int i = pane.indexOfTabComponent(ButtonTabComponent.this);
                    if (i != -1) {
                        return pane.getTitleAt(i);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };

            add(label);
            //add more space between the label and the button
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 5));
            //tab button
            JButton button = new TabButton();
            add(button);
            //add more space to the top of the component
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 0, 0, 0));
        }

        private class TabButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

            public TabButton() {
                int size = 17;
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
                setToolTipText("close this tab");
                //Make the button looks the same for all Laf's
                setUI(new BasicButtonUI());
                //Make it transparent
                setContentAreaFilled(false);
                //No need to be focusable
                setFocusable(false);
                setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
                setBorderPainted(false);
                //Making nice rollover effect
                //we use the same listener for all buttons
                addMouseListener(buttonMouseListener);
                setRolloverEnabled(true);
                //Close the proper tab by clicking the button
                addActionListener(this);
            }

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int i = pane.indexOfTabComponent(ButtonTabComponent.this);
                if (i != -1) {
                    Component comp = pane.getComponentAt(i);
                    if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
                        JLabel label = (JLabel) comp;
                        System.out.println("Label text = " + label.getText());
                        switch (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure you want to close the \"" + pane.getTitleAt(i) + "\" tab?", "Close", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION)) {
                            case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
                                pane.remove(i);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //we don't want to update UI for this button
            public void updateUI() {
            }

            //paint the cross
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                //shift the image for pressed buttons
                if (getModel().isPressed()) {
                    g2.translate(1, 1);
                }
                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                if (getModel().isRollover()) {
                    g2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                }
                int delta = 6;
                g2.drawLine(delta, delta, getWidth() - delta - 1, getHeight() - delta - 1);
                g2.drawLine(getWidth() - delta - 1, delta, delta, getHeight() - delta - 1);
                g2.dispose();
            }
        }

        private final static MouseListener buttonMouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                Component component = e.getComponent();
                if (component instanceof AbstractButton) {
                    AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) component;
                    button.setBorderPainted(true);
                }
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                Component component = e.getComponent();
                if (component instanceof AbstractButton) {
                    AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) component;
                    button.setBorderPainted(false);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```